# OL li numbering issue

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've the following ordered list:

```
<ol>     
    <li>First</li>
    <li>Second</li>
    <li>Third</li>
</ol>
```

I've to display one li at a time which I'm doing using the 'display' property. The problem is that no matter which of the li's is displayed, the list numbering shows 1. So instead of "2. Second" or "3. Third" I'm seeing "1. Second", "1. Third", etc.

Comment: It is extremely unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Do you mean that other li's that are hidden are not occupying space? use `visibility` instead of `display`.

Comment: Where's your code for changing the LI being displayed?

Comment: @j08691 Initially the complete list is hidden and then I'm using $('li').not(':eq(2)').show()

Comment: You need to post a complete code example, one that allows us to reproduce the issue. Also try adding a jsFiddle to your question whenever possible.

Comment: Sorry for the unclear questions, here is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/xtFSN/

Comment: @AnandNalya Your issue is as i mentioned in my comment, if it is display:none li starts counting from what is visible. You need to use visibility and plus some hack say making height of non displayed div to 0.. Check this http://jsfiddle.net/SnZD2/

Comment: @AnandNalya You want this http://jsfiddle.net/Vj9Sy/

Comment: @JoshC Do you also think OP is looking for this only..?

Comment: @PSL Yep, I think that's the answer - i'd upvote it - you were the first person to suggest using visibility.

Comment: To be frank, had this question been worded properly this would have made a good question.

Comment: @PSL Yea. I don't think it's a duplicate either. Retracted my close vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I understood from your question `I've to display one li at a time`, You can use `start` attribute to start from a certain index.

```
<ol>
    <li>First</li> <!-- 1 -->
    <li>Second</li> <!-- 2 -->
    <li>Third</li> <!-- 3 -->
</ol>

<ol>
    <li>First</li> <!-- 1 (default)-->
</ol>

<ol start="2">
    <li>Second</li> <!-- 2 -->
</ol>

<ol start="3">
    <li>Third</li> <!-- 3 -->
</ol>

<ol start="50">
    <li>Fifty</li>
    <li>Fifty One</li>
</ol>
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/pJ7yg/1/)

**Update:**

```
$('li').hide();
var index = 2, li = $('li').eq(index);
li.closest('ol').attr('start', index+1).find(li).show();
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/xtFSN/2/)

**Update:** (make a function)

```
function hideLiByIndex(i)
{
    $('li').hide();
    li = $('li').eq(i);
    li.closest('ol').attr('start', i+1).find(li).show();
}

hideLiByIndex(1);
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/xtFSN/3/)

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the question (unclear) and your fiddle it seems like you want the hidden div's to retain their list order number and visible to show their respective list number rather that start over from 1. This is not possible with jquery `.hide()` and `.show()` because they use display property which changes the list's ordinal number. You need to use visibility.

Try

```
$('li').not(':eq(2)')
          .css('height', '0px') //Use this only if you dont want to show the lists that are hidden because visibility takes space in the page flow.
          .end().filter(':eq(2)')
          .css('visibility', 'visible');
```

and a css

```
ol li {
    visibility : hidden; /*Or just use jquery to set the css to visibility hidden*/
}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MREDd/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try hiding the divs using

```
visibility: hidden;
```

and changing it to

```
visibility: visible;
```

when you want it to show

**jQuery**

To show:

```
$(element).css("visibility","visible");
```

To hide:

```
$(element).css("visibility","hidden");
```